# codeigniter remote file upload?

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

the file validation of CI is good. but it is not offering any feature to fetch an file from a remote url . So is there any way in which I can utilize the file uploading class to do the validation etc ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very sure about what are you asking, but upload class itself can validate the file uploaded. You can check several parameters like file/mime type, size. ¿What do you need to validate?

Comment: it will validate the file which was uploaded via form .. I want to download a file to a temp directory using curl, then I want to use codeigniter to process the upload.

Comment: CI upload lib is based on $_FILES, so you can process the file faking the array with you file's data. Basically the upload lib moves the file from the dir where server puts the downloads to the point you store the upload, checking mime types and things like that.

Comment: server does the upload part, i don't see the point of upload it via curl. How do you validate the file? I don't find connection between form and curl.